# Synaptics driver for Windows 10 (Acer Aspire E1-571)

Tags: windows-10, mouse, device-driver

I have an Acer Aspire E1-571 that had a Synaptics touchpad driver preinstalled on it. Some time back, a corrupted Microsoft Office update corrupted the file registry of the entire HDD on my laptop. I consequently replaced the stock HDD with a 500gb Kingston SSD.

The problem is that now I don't have a touch pad driver and instead just have the default Windows preset system that's clean and has nothing on it (I even had to rebuy a copy of Microsoft Office). This means I've lost the functionality of my touch pad that I had such as two finger scroll and the new Windows 10 functionalities.

Can I still find and install the original driver for my touch pad so that the OEM functions can be restored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked for your laptop at the manufacturer website and I found Win 8 and Win 7 drivers.

http://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/drivers

Choose <kbd>Notebook</kbd> → <kbd>Aspire</kbd> → <kbd>E1-571</kbd>

You can see touchpad drivers listed there.

In that website you can see a list of the available drivers provided by your manufacturer. You can choose whichever you want depending on your OS and hardware.

Comment: Just a quick question, are there any risks involved with installing a driver?

Comment: Hmm. The driver is provided by your manufacturer. I'm sure they've tested it, a lot. If you try to install wrong driver a) Installer will warn you, b) You cannot use your device properly. For example, my brother installed wrong VGA driver. Everytime he scrolled on a web page, he got blue screen. We switch the driver with original, problem solved. However, I can't be sure about drivers that you find with 3rd party tools.